# Ionic /How to select multiple options from select control(Maximum selection will 3 options only)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic 1.3.16 version currently. Here I need to select multiple options in my select control.

Here my ionic HTML code:

```
<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
            Lightsaber
        </div>
        <select>
            <option>Blue</option>
            <option selected>Green</option>
            <option>Red</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: use `multiple` attribute on select with `ng-model`

Comment: use multiple also not working...with ng-model

Comment: could you print the same `ng-model` & check whether it is changing value or not

Comment: i am adding options dynamically..using ng-repeat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the `value` attribute in `select` option, because when you select option it will reflect to the `ng-model`.Additionally to select multiple you need to add `multiple` attribute in your select.

**Markup**

```
<select ng-model="selectedValues" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
{{selectedValues}}
```

Comment: my code also the same but when we are adding select with multiple attribute it is not working...

Comment: @user3326931 you missed to add value attribute in option..do upvote if it does helped you..Thanks

Comment: how to set the the maximum multiple selection is 3

Comment: only angularjs only have to fix..i will not use jquery

Comment: you can use just angular to disable a ui-item if it reaches a certain condition quite easily. Just do ng-disabled:
<option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.value}}" ng-disabled='selectedValues.length >= 3'>{{option.name}}</option>
or at least that should work.

Comment: I've got a bug report from a client where multi select does not work on her device. It works on all our devices. But multiple is not a very new thing in the HTML world. Does it help to change it to multiple="multiple" for old Android versions? We don't have devices here where it does not work.

Comment: because I was also trying to do the same, its works on browser but on android/ios it does not.

Comment: What do you mean by `it does not work?` can you provide online replication of the problem on emulator?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `multiple` attribute in the select field.

```
<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
   <div class="input-label">
       Lightsaber
   </div>
   <select multiple="multiple">
        <option>Blue</option>
        <option selected>Green</option>
        <option>Red</option>
   </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Any error? because the multiple attribute gives you the option for selecting multiple options=

Comment: You're probably testing in browser, test it in the emulator and this will work. It's far from ideal though

Answer (score 1):

use ng-options to bind data, here is how

in the controller

```
$scope.values=  [
   {id:1, name:"value1" }, 
   {id:2, name:"value2" }, 
   {id:3, name:"value3" }
   ];
$scope.selectedValues= []; //initial selections
```

and in the view

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">

     <select multiple ng-model='selectedValues'
                    ng-options="a.name for a in values" >
     </select>
</label>
{{selectedValues}} <!-- to preview the selection -->
```